# Is neurolinguistic programming effective in influencing sales processes?

Tags: neuro-linguistic-prog, neuromarketing, validation

In my country neurolinguistic programming (NLP) has become very popular in sales departments. Therefore, I wonder if there are any experiments which examine the contribution of NLP to the sales process. 
I was especially curious when I heard that [Bander sued Grinder](http://skepdic.com/neurolin.html).

- Are there any peer-reviewed validation studies of NLP?
- Particularly, has any peer-reviewed research examined the effect of NLP on sales?

Comment: When you talk about "NLP", you don't talk about "scientifically reproducible results", you are betting on the placebo effect. Where if the subject thinks it's effective, It'll probably be effective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Section "[Scientific Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming#Scientific_evaluation)" in the Wikipedia article on NLP sums up current research nicely:

**None of the claimed effects have been validated.**

Scientists consider NLP a pseudoscience with aggressive marketing and a name and jargon that deludes people seeking help by "[giving] the impression of scientific respectability" (quoted from that section).

Answer (score 5):

Here are a number of references for you:

The article ["The effect of neurolinguistic programming on organisational and individual performance: a case study"](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/journals.htm?articleid=837100&show=abstract) (Thompson et al. 2002), is primarily a case study of the effect of NLP training on managers and workers of the hospitality industry.

The article ["Neuro-linguistic programming and learning theory: a response"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0958517032000137667#.UddBk_h--M8) (Tosey and Mathison, 2003), looks at the research in NLP as a whole.

This article, though a bit dated (1984), ["NLP techniques for salespeople"](http://psycnet.apa.org/psycinfo/1985-10948-001) (Stanley, 1984), looks at the NLP techniques of salespeople and the ideas are revisiting in ["NLP revisited: nonverbal communications and signals of trustworthiness"](http://mesharpe.metapress.com/app/home/contribution.asp?referrer=parent&backto=issue,7,9;journal,30,43;linkingpublicationresults,1:110659,1) (Wood, 2006).

Whether NLP can help or harm a business is discussed in ["Can NLP help or harm your business?"](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/journals.htm?articleid=1541478&show=abstract) (Yemm, 2006).

Hope this helps.