# Is Neuro-Linguistic Programming (NLP) a science or pseudoscience?

Tags: neuro-linguistic-prog

**Are there some branches of NLP which are considered scientific?**

> Bandler and Grinder also claim that NLP can treat problems such as
>   phobias, depression, habit disorder, psychosomatic illnesses,
>   myopia,<sup>[8]</sup> allergy, common cold<sup>[9]</sup> and learning disorders, often in a
>   single session.<sup>[10]</sup><sup>[11]</sup><sup>[12]</sup><sup>[13]</sup> NLP has been adopted by some
>   hypnotherapists and in seminars marketed to business and
>   government.<sup>[14]</sup><sup>[15]</sup> Reviews of empirical research find that NLP's core
>   tenets are poorly supported.<sup>[16]</sup> The balance of scientific evidence
>   reveals NLP to be a largely discredited pseudoscience. Scientific
>   reviews show it contains numerous factual errors,<sup>[14]</sup><sup>[17]</sup> and fails to
>   produce the results asserted by proponents.<sup>[16]</sup><sup>[18]</sup> According to
>   Devilly (2005),<sup>[19]</sup> NLP has had a consequent decline in prevalence
>   since the 1970s. Criticisms go beyond lack of empirical evidence for
>   effectiveness, saying NLP exhibits pseudoscientific
>   characteristics,<sup>[19]</sup> title,<sup>[20]</sup> concepts and terminology as
>   well.<sup>[21]</sup><sup>[22]</sup> NLP is cited as an example of pseudoscience when
>   teaching scientific literacy at the professional and university
>   level.<sup>[23]</sup><sup>[24]</sup><sup>[25]</sup><sup>[26]</sup><sup>[27]</sup><sup>[28]</sup><sup>[29]</sup><sup>[30]</sup><sup>[31]</sup><sup>[32]</sup> NLP also appears on
>   peer reviewed expert-consensus based lists of discredited
>   interventions.<sup>[16]</sup>

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming). I've made a fast search on Wikipedia, but I cannot access the papers. Also, going deep into this topic would be really demanding.

Comment: Please, if you choose to downvote I would really appreciate an explanation, to avoid the same error the next time.

Comment: Please read the tag wiki, the tag `nlp` is not for neurolinguistic programming.

Comment: That's okay.  Mousing over the tag will give you the excerpt.  Clicking on it (and then clicking "learn more...") will take you to the actual wiki.

Comment: Interesting. At one time, didn't most in the medical field announce Louis Pasteur and Elizabeth Kelly as Charlatans and frauds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have quite a few questions on this site about [Neuro-linguistic-programming](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neuro-linguistic-prog). In general I think it is more productive to talk about a particular scientific claim or a particular treatment rather than an entire paradigm. Paradigms that are not grounded in the scientific method may incidentally reflect the truth when studied relative to scientific standards.

In general, [this question on NLP and sales effectiveness has mostly been answered in a general sense](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/is-neurolinguistic-programming-effective-in-influenceing-sales-processes). In particular, [@what's answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/3793/52) makes reference to the [scientific evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming#Scientific_evaluation) section on Wikipedia which basically states that NLP is not scientifically based or validated.

Comment: Interesting.. it seemed to me a bit "invented", even if I'd like to wait before classifying it as completely ineffective. Sometimes scientific discoveries starts from intuition and a scientific approach is really time-demanding. For example, as far as I know, Dale Carnegie is also missing of scientific evidence.. but it's really intuitive that it works in many many cases.