# Are there scientific alternatives to Neuro-Linguistic Programming (NLP)?

Tags: neuro-linguistic-prog

According to these answers [1](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6062/is-neuro-linguistic-programming-nlp-a-science-or-pseudoscience/6069#6069), [2](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/is-neurolinguistic-programming-effective-in-influenceing-sales-processes) and to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming#Scientific_evaluation), NLP seems to be a pseudoscience, which has shown no real effectiveness, and so on.

Are there scientific proved alternatives to NLP?

Comment: What do you mean by "alternatives to NLP"? NLP claims to do several things; which of them are you looking to do scientifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general [positive psychology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_psychology), [coaching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaching), and counselling are all fields that endeavour to help people achieve their potential. All these areas have scientific literature built around them. That said, there is a degree to which coaching and counselling are practical skills. Most psychologists aspire to follow the scientist-practitioner model. That said, specific practitioners may vary in the degree to which they follow this model versus using more intuitive approaches.